# C# cant get data from database table in combobox

Tags: c#, sql

when i load my application i need to fill the combobox `cbkeuze` with the row `loginnaam` from table `gebruik`

The error I am getting is: Can't change the items because property Data Source is set.

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // SQL Connectie opzetten
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
            Conn.ConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Wachtwoord;Data Source=LAPTOP-PDI9B3LP\SCHOOL";
            Conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = Conn;
            // Alles selecteren van tabel Favorieten
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from gebruik";
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // Tabel wegschrijven in Applicatie
                string loginnaam = dr.GetString(0);
                cbKeuze.Items.Add(loginnaam);
            }
            dr.Close();
            // Database connectie sluiten
            Conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Try to search where in your program there is a line like _cbKeuze.DataSource =_ You can set the DataSource and then try to manually add items at the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your combobox properties and see if `DataSource` is initiated

Comment: I did it added this line `// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'wachtwoordDataSet1.gebruik' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.gebruikTableAdapter1.Fill(this.wachtwoordDataSet1.gebruik);` But I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can add loginnaam's to List loginnaams until while loop ends. After dr.Close() line, use cbKeuze.DataSource = loginnaams.
This will work for you.